# How to 'explode' this page output

Tags: php, curl, newline, explode

I'm trying to parse the output of this page -> http://master.anti3d.com/raw_server_list2.php

The documentation of that master server says that every entry is separated in this way

> Note: LF = LineFeed = 10
>
> Format:
>   serverName[LF]ipAddress:port;users/maxusers;gameCount;version;location[LF]
>
> Example:
>
> Server Name1
>
> 111.111.111.1111:27888;0/25;0.86;USA
>
> Server Name2
>
> 222.222.222.2222:27888;0/50;0.86;Canada

so I'm using OOCurl library for retrieving the site data using object oriented CURL

```
<?php

include_once('oocurl.php');

$fetchmaster = new Curl('http://master.anti3d.com/raw_server_list2.php');
$data = $fetchmaster->exec();
$parsedata = explode('\n', $data);
print_r($parsedata);
?>
```

Curl retrieves the page info but when I try to explode using \n character or newline, ASCII 10, it just doesn't works. I downloaded the page output and saw it with an hex editor and it's using \x0a, \n, linefeed

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the single quotes in

```
$parsedata = explode('\n', $data);
```

to double quotes to properly encode a newline.

```
$parsedata = explode("\n", $data);
```

For example:

```
print '\n'; // prints a backslash, followed by the letter n
print "\n"; // prints a newline
```

[Strings in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note:  Unlike the two other syntaxes,
>   variables and **escape sequences** for
>   special characters **will not be
>   expanded** when they occur in single
>   quoted strings.